# OpenJDK update in RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, java

We need to apply the JDK updates to one of the RHEL 6 servers. How do I apply the patch if I have the RPM package available, which I have downloaded from the internet. Searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find any steps on how to apply the JDK patch.

Also, what precautions should be taken before applying the new RPM update, so that the current functionality is not disturbed?

The package installed in the server is:  `java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-3.1.13.1.el6_5`

I want to update it to:  `java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el6_5`

Comment: What do you have exactly? Add the filenames/package names to the question.

Comment: The package installed in the server is: java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-3.1.13.1.el6_5

I want to update it to: java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el6_5  Need the exact steps to apply the RPM update

Answer (score 2):

Take a backup first.

Run:

```
# cd <directory where new RPM is located>
# yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el6_5.rpm
```

If things don't go well and the previous version's RPM is available to the system, you can roll back with:

```
# yum history undo last
```

If it's not on the system, you can downgrade by re-installing the previous version (after [downloading](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25506356/dir/centos_6/com/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-3.1.13.1.el6_5.x86_64.rpm.html) it first) with:

```
# cd <directory where original version RPM is located>
# yum downgrade java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-3.1.13.1.el6_5.rpm
```